# gnuplot - how to read the & character from dat file

Tags: character, gnuplot

I am reading a .dat File and one of headings of a Column contains the & character. When I try to plot the columns via Gnuplot the & character disapears in the name of the function. I am using the columnheader function to get the name. How do I have to adjust the name of the Column?

Current Column headings:
i D&C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can double escape the & character in the data file like this:

```
i D\\&C
1 4
2 3
3 5
```

Now the plot command works:

```
plot "a.dat" w lp title columnheader
```

This is the result:

[image: & character in columnheader]